# AppFog No configuration could be found for a session named 'default'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, cloud-foundry, appfog

In my mongoid.yml I have

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      host:
        - <%= JSON.parse(ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'])['mongodb-1.8'].first['credentials']['hostname'] rescue 'localhost' %>
      port: <%= JSON.parse( ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'] )['mongodb-1.8'].first['credentials']['port'] rescue 27017 %>
      database:  <%= JSON.parse( ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'] )['mongodb-1.8'].first['credentials']['db'] rescue 'tutorial_db' %>
      username: <%= JSON.parse( ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'] )['mongodb-1.8'].first['credentials']['username'] rescue '' %>
      password: <%= JSON.parse( ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'] )['mongodb-1.8'].first['credentials']['password'] rescue '' %>
```

When deploying to AppFog I keep getting

```
ActionView::Template::Error (
Problem:
  No configuration could be found for a session named 'default'.
Summary:
  When attempting to create the new session, Mongoid could not find a session configuration for the name: 'default'. This is
necessary in order to know the host, port, and options needed to connect.
Resolution:
  Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure under the sessions key that a configuration exists for 'default'. If you have se
t the configuration programatically, ensure that 'default' exists in the configuration hash.):
```

Comment: Recently it occurred to me. And the server was running in Production mode so changed it to Development, then everything worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

the correct key is "hosts:" no "host:"

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#configuration